# How to disable v-pagination when there are not items VUEJS + VUETIFY

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, disable, paginator

I want to disable the buttons when there are no items in the list or there is only one page

```
<v-model="currentPage"
      :length="lastPage"
      total-visible="10"
      prev-icon="mdi-menu-left"
      next-icon="mdi-menu-right"
      @input="handlePageChange"
      class="elevation-0"
      >
</v-pagination>
```

JS

```
getCountries() {
            axios
                .get("api/countries/get?page=${this.currentPage}`)
                .then(response => {
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.tableLoading = false;
                    this.countries = response.data.data;
                    this.currentPage = response.data.current_page;
                    this.lastPage = response.data.last_page;                 

                });
        },
```

[image]

Comment: You could probably check the total amount and also the lastPage and hide the pagination with some CSS. Looking like this `:class="[elementsNoneOrOnePageOnly ? 'hidding-class' : '']"` on the `v-pagination` component.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Vuetify provides `disabled` props on almost every component. So I think you could just add `:disabled="lastPage <2"` in your v-pagination props